# Compute HSL main color values (red, yellow, green, magenta, blue and purple)

Tags: colors, hsv, hsl

How do I mathematically compute the values for [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) main colors?
I can hardcode them in the program, of course, but I remain interested how can I determine if the color is main or combined. There must be an inscribed hexagon in the HSL color circle, so I need angles on which its corners lay.

Comment: Wikipedia, who's always your friend, has a nice treatment including the mathematics [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Comment: I'll make sure to read the topic more carefully, but, since I have linked to the wikipedia myself, you could assume my knowledge about the page and, at least, post the  `url#something` link to the right section.

Comment: Sure, example values of popular colors are at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Examples, and the derivation of how to do the computation at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Formal_derivation, although it may be too wordy for what you're looking for.